# MySql fails to update

Tags: mysql

In the past two years we use MySql for keeping data for nightly builds of our C++ projects. DB is fairly small, and has a few triggers on it.
Recently it began failing on updates rather frequently. We deleted some unnecessary old records and situation improved a little, however failure still happens.

We've tried to look at the error logs, nothing significant there (unless error logging isn't configured correctly).

Can someone give a hint as to where we should look?
Are there any diagnostic modes that can help us track the problems?

I'd be happy to elaborate on missing info..

Comment: Have you checked the disc space on the server? Is this windows or linux? Have you checked the syslog?

Comment: Must add that there were no changes in how DB was used, no change in triggers etc. Only records added.

Comment: AliGibbs: 9GB free, linux. Haven't checked syslog - what should I look for there?

Comment: More importantly you should check the mysql error log. In a standard installation it should be located in /var/log/ directory. If it is not there check the configuration file for user specified location.

Comment: The error log didn't reveal much. Is there any way to configure error logging level?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the server type, so I'm going to assume that it's some flavour of Linux.  If that's the case, you can enable debug logging in your `my.cnf` file, usually found somewhere like `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.  Here's the relevant snippet from mine:

```
# you need the debug USE flag enabled to use the following directives,
# if needed, uncomment them, start the server and issue 
# #tail -f /tmp/mysqld.sql /tmp/mysqld.trace
# this will show you *exactly* what's happening in your server ;)

#log                                            = /tmp/mysqld.sql
#gdb
#debug                                          = d:t:i:o,/tmp/mysqld.trace
#one-thread
```

Note that the *debug USE flag* mentioned above is a reference to the distribution I use (Gentoo) and that other distros may or may not install MySQL with debugging support.  If they don't though, they usually have it as a separate package.  On Ubuntu for example, I think this package is called `libmysqld-pic`.

Anyway, make sure that debugging is enabled in `my.cnf`, restart the server and watch `/tmp/mysqld.sql` and `/tmp/mysqld.trace` to see what's going on.  Remember not to leave this on permanently though as it's a big performance hit.